# Há diferença entre Task.FromResult e Task.Factory.StartNew?

Tags: c#, .net, task

Dado um método em preciso retornar uma `Task<T>`.

Exemplo:

```
public Task<MyResult> Handle();
```

Posso fazer as seguintes implementações:

Assim:

```
public Task<MyResult> Handle()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        // alguma coisa
    }

    return Task.FromResult(new MyResult());
}
```

e assim:

```
public Task<MyResult> Handle()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            // alguma coisa
        }

        return new MyResult();
    });
}
```

- Há alguma diferença entre essas implementações?
- Qual seria a mais recomendada?
- No primeiro exemplo, pode haver perca de performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Há alguma diferença entre essas implementações?

O primeiro apenas cria um resultado de uma tarefa, ele não executa uma tarefa. Se você precisa executar uma tarefa ele não deve ser usado. A função dele é encapsular um objeto em uma tarefa, não executá-la. Não quer dizer que não executa o método, apenas que isso não será feito como uma tarefa.

O segundo executa uma tarefa e entrega um resultado. Entendo que só está criando uma `Task` para atender a demanda do método que está implementando que exige aquela assinatura, então não tem porque usar isso.

> Qual seria a mais recomendada?

O primeiro, se pode usá-la. Se precisar fazer o segundo considere usar `Task.Run()`. Pode [ler mais sobre](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

> No primeiro exemplo, pode haver perca de performance?

O oposto, normalmente. Não quer dizer que é o melhor sempre, ser mais rápido para executar é diferente de entregar o resultado da melhor forma. Mas não pense que haverá grande diferença, é algo mínimo. Como não está executando assincronamente não vi vantagem no segundo, é só complicação.

Se `MyResult()` for muito demorado pode ser interessante, em alguns cenários, fazer a execução ser assíncrona para não bloquear a execução, mas não fará nada ser executado mais rápido. Se ele demorar pouco a assincronicidade pode ser prejudicial mesmo executando em paralelo.

Comment: Vou dar uma lida nesse arquivo, nunca tinha lido nada sobre isso... Valeu